# Html5 Picture element

Tags: html, css, webp, srcset

I have the following code, which I am using for image-gallery, but am not able to make it work:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="/web/gallery/17/1567772625.webp" type="image/webp"> 
  <source srcset="/web/gallery/17/1567772625.jpg" type="image/jpg"> 
  <source srcset="/web/gallery/17/1567772625-thumb.webp" type="image/webp"> 
  <source srcset="/web/gallery/17/1567772625-thumb.jpg" type="image/jpg"> 
  <a class="mg-image-wrap" data-title="Snaps From The Resort" href="/web/gallery/17/1567772625.jpg">
    <img alt="Snaps From The Resort" class="mg-image" data-position="0" src="/web/gallery/17/1567772625-thumb.jpg" />
  </a>                                             
</picture>
```

However, if I change the code to the following:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="/web/gallery/17/1567772625-thumb.webp" type="image/webp"> 
  <source srcset="/web/gallery/17/1567772625-thumb.jpg" type="image/jpg"> 
  <img  src="/web/gallery/17/1567772625-thumb.jpg" />
</picture>
```

I have two questions:

1. How I can make the the first block download webp, where supported, particularly thumbnail image is downloaded as jpg?
2. How to prevent href image not to download till user click on href link?

Answer (score 1):

### Picture element

Well, first of all, only `<source>` and `<img>` [elements are allowed INSIDE](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) a `<picture>`. That means if want it to link somewhere you should wrap the picture in the anchor tag or use a javascript click handler on the picture.

```
<a href="#">
  <picture>...</picture>
</a>
```

### Using Webp

You should treat the `<picture>` as a single element with multiple properties just like any other image. This means thumbnails and gallery images are separate and use JS to interact/change the "visible" image.

Basically, the browser grabs the first image that matches its abilities. (that's why the img tag is last)

You CAN specify different sized images inside a `picture` element by using `media-queries` BUT **those are designed to load different images based on layout size NOT for different interactions/use cases**.

Example:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="imageOne.jpg" type="image/jpg" media="(min-width: 1400px)">
    <source srcset="mediumImg.jpg" type="image/jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <source srcset="smallImg.jpg" type="image/jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">  
    <img  src="fallback.jpg" />
</picture>
```

This will cause the device to load different images based on device width...

---

You can also add any [additional attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) directly on the picture tag like you would any other image.

```
<picture class="mg-image" data-position="0" >
   ...
</picture>
```

Comment: Hi Bryce, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't resolves the issue I am facing. like `<a href=''>` is also a link to image, how I can use the same `<picture` element for that?

Comment: The anchor tag CANNOT be INSIDE the picture element. Put the picture inside the anchor instead.